# When will a village decide to go to war?

Tags: reus

I recently had the chance to complete the "Barracks" project upgrade to a School, but one of the requirements is that the village has to have won at least one war. I tried to increase its greed (it even had a war marker for a little bit), but it didn't wage war on its tiny neighbor (~50 prosperity vs. ~200). How do war markers work? How can I push a village to wage war, and how can I prevent a village from waging a war?

**What are the mechanics of war?**

Comment: Villages declare war when greed goes up. Greed goes up by expanding too quickly, especially with other villages around.

Comment: Someone told me that villages will typically try to go to war with the easiest target around them when their greed goes up, and determining the "easiest" target includes village distance and size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most surefire way to start a war is with Greed. High greed villages will always attack their neighbors.

A village that decides to go to war will take the Geography into account. They are more likely to attack a neighbor without oceans or mountains in their way.

A village will usually try to attack their weakest neighbor. Military strength of a village tends to correspond to their prosperity, and how much Danger is in their borders.

A village that is too busy defending itself from Danger in its borders will not go to war, nor will their Greed increase. However, over time villages get better at keeping Danger at bay, and in the long run they get stronger because of it (if it does not destroy them or vice versa).

A village that has won many wars will tend to go to war again.

Comment: +1; I like this answer the most so far, but it still doesn't address the mechanics of war. I'm looking for an answer that addresses the mechanics of war overall, not just in terms of greed. I've seen hints that say villages that have won a war are more likely to declare war. I'm looking for mechanics like that.

Comment: Edited accordingly

Comment: +1, great answer. But... where did you get all this info? Is there any authoritative/detailed source anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Well..since you are just starting the game,just try to finish some of the projects started by your citizens then along the line some other citizens will get angry and wage wars...
Give them some natural boons and they get greedy and wage wars

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the *tiny* village to declare war on the larger one, just by putting down a couple of good resources (a couple of quartzes, say, or something that works well with the tiny village's project), letting the small village grow quickly and hopefully greedy, removing the resources and putting them back again.

I'm not sure that the tiny village will pick its direct neighbor to declare war upon but at least it's worth a shot!